# Using Automapper to map multiple ID properties to single Name property

Tags: automapper, dto

I have a User entity with a Name property that I need to link back to three Id-based properties in a DTO.

**User Entity**

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

**Album Entity**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public int Artist { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Producer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Designer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public User User {get; set; }
```

**AlbumDTO**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public int Artist { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Producer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Designer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public string ArtistName { get; set; } // <-- need this to be User.Name
public string ProducerName { get; set; } // <-- need this to be User.Name
public string DesignerName { get; set; } // <-- need this to be User.Name
```

I'm trying to map it something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Album, AlbumDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ArtistName , opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.User.Name));
```

But this just throws a mapping error ("cannot find column 'User_Id'").

What is the proper syntax for lining up AlbumDto.ArtistName with User.Name by matching AlbumDto.Artist to User.Id?

Comment: Are you sure this is an AutoMapper issue? What happens if you query `s.User.Name` without AM?

Answer (score 0):

That code works for me. I am using Automapper 3.3.0

Also you can write a Test and use Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); after CreateMap to ensure that the mapping is created without exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different route and skipping the Automapping code I was trying to write.

Here's how the new entities and DTO turned out:

**User Entity**

```
public User() //<-- new code
        {
            Albums = new List<Album>();
        }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string SSN { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; } //<-- new code
```

**Album Entity**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public int Artist { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Producer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Designer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public User ArtistUser {get; set; } //<-- new code
```

**Mapping in dbContext OnModelCreating()**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Album>().HasOptional(t => t.ArtistUser)
                .WithMany(t => t.Albums)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Artist);
```

**Album DTO**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public int Artist { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Producer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public int Designer { get; set; } // <-- this ties to User.Id
public string ArtistUserName { get; set; } // <-- new code gets Artist Name from User.Name
```